# How to skip dollar sign while assigning sqlplus output to a shell variable?

Tags: bash

I need to query table using sqlplus and assign the value to a shell variable.Currently while doing i am getting issues.Code which i am trying currently is

```
columnValue=`sqlplus -s username/muk\$mh@hostname:port/servicename  <<EOF $value1
set heading off;
set scan on;
select column1 from table where ID='$id';
EXIT;
EOF`
echo $columnValue
```

where muk$mh is my db password .I am trying to skip the $ sign with escape character but still its failing.
Any way by which i can resolve this.
Thanks

Comment: Your example contains multiple dubious constructs as well as at least one syntax error.  It would be good to verify that the code you post illustrates the problem you are trying to solve, and ideally nothing else; see also the guide for creating a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure about the exact problem you are facing, but I can see there is an issue with the escape character.  Since you want shell to expand the password variable ($mh), you should not escape the $ character.  Try this:

```
columnValue=`sqlplus -s username/muk$mh@hostname:port/servicename  <<EOF
set heading off;
set scan on;
select column1 from table where ID='$id';
EXIT;
EOF`
echo $columnValue
```

If '$mh' is literally a part of your password, then I would think "$value1" at the end of first line could be a problem.

Comment: Got the same error when tried the above approach - "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied SP2-0306:"

Comment: columnValue=exec(sqlplus -s username/muk$mh@hostname:port/servicename  <<EOF $value1
set heading off;
set scan on;
select column1 from table where ID='$id';
EXIT;
EOF)
echo $columnValue                            ==> I need to tryout this.

Answer (score 0):

A single backslash is not sufficient inside backticks to escape a literal dollar sign.

The backtick syntax is obsolete anyway; you should use modern `$(command substitution)` syntax, which has more straightforward quoting rules, too.

```
bash$ var=`echo moo\$bar`
bash$ echo "$var"
moo
bash$ var=$(echo moo\$bar)
bash$ echo "$var"
moo$bar
```